# Yuumi’s you and me untargetable questions

Tags: league-of-legends

I am playing Yuumi in League of Legends and I have some questions about her ability, You and Me . Here is a description of the ability You and Me:

> Passive: While Attached, Yuumi and her ally share 12 / 14 / 16 / 18 /
> 20 (+12 / 14 / 16 / 18 / 20%) adaptive force, granting each other
> bonus attack damage or ability power (depending on which their ally
> has more of) equal to a percentage of their own attack damage or
> ability power (depending on which of the two is higher).
>
> Yuumi starts the game with one point in You and Me!, while Prowling
> Projectile has 6 ranks.
>
> Active: After a 0.25 second delay, Yuumi dashes to an ally champion
> and attaches to them. While Attached, she follows her ally's movement
> and is untargetable by everything except tower damage. Yuumi's
> abilities fire from her ally's location, and she can't attack enemies.
>
> Yuumi can switch among her teammates without a cooldown. If Yuumi
> re-activates the ability without a valid target, she will detach from
> her ally and dash up to 250 units in the target direction. Yuumi also
> detaches automatically if the ally she is attached to dies.
> Immobilizing Yuumi places this ability on a 5 second cooldown. Silence
> doesn't count as an immobilizing effect that places You and Me! on a 5
> second cooldown.

But some things are confusing me.

1. When Yuumi activates the ability she dashes to the ally to become untargetable, so my question is can she be hit by abilities while she is dashing?
2. If Yuumi is taking damage over time, for example Ignite or Teemo's mushroom poison, will she still take the damage when she becomes untargetable or will the damage stop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When Yuumi activates the ability she dashes to the ally to become untargetable, so my question is can she be hit by abilities while she is dashing?

Yep! Being crowd controlled while attempting to attach to a champion will immediately cancel You and Me! and incurs the 5 second cooldown mentioned at the end of the ability's description. Conditional stuns that involve passing terrain to be stunned, like Veigar's E, will still stun Yuumi if she hits the wall while travelling using You and Me!

Yuumi is *only* untargetable *while* she's attached to an allied champion.

> If Yuumi is taking damage over time, for example Ignite or Teemo's mushroom poison, will she still take the damage when she becomes untargetable or will the damage stop?

Yuumi will continue to take damage from any damage over time effects while attached to a champion. The untargetability granted by Yuumi's W will not cancel any pending debuffs or damage over time effects. This is consistent with all other spells that make champions untargetable.

An important note here is that Yuumi's untargetability doesn't truly work for towers like other untargetable effects. If Yuumi is attached to an allied champion while underneath an enemy tower and Yuumi gets turret aggro by dealing damage to an enemy champion, she will actually start being hit by the turret. If either she or the ally she is attached to leaves the turret range this will reset as normal, though.